# Animating the letters in a word w the app opens - SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui

I'm trying to get a dancing letters effect when my app first opens.

I'm close. The coding below almost does what I want. I use a ForEach loop to loop through the letters of the word and apply an animation to each letter. And I use the onAppear function to set the drag amount when the app opens.

With this coding I can get the 'forward' motion but I can't get the animation to reverse so that the letters end up in their original position. I've tried adding a repeat with reverse, but, again, the letters never return to their original position

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
  let letters = Array("Math Fun!")
  @State private var enabled = false
  @State private var dragAmount = CGSize.zero

  var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
      ForEach(0..<letters.count) { num in
        Text(String(self.letters[num]))
          .padding(5)
          .font(.title)
          .background(self.enabled ? Color.blue : Color.red)
          .offset(self.dragAmount)
          .animation(Animation.default.delay(Double(num)/20).repeatCount(3, autoreverses: true))
      }
    }
    .onAppear {
      self.dragAmount = CGSize(width: 0, height: 80)
      self.enabled.toggle()
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update: with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Animation is based on changed states, we switched states and view animated to the new states, so to rollback we need to switch the states back.

Here is the possible approach (might still require tuning, but is ok for demo)

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let letters = Array("Math Fun!")
    @State private var enabled = false
    @State private var dragAmount = CGSize.zero

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<letters.count, id: \.self) { num in
                Text(String(self.letters[num]))
                    .padding(5)
                    .font(.title)
                    .background(self.enabled ? Color.blue : Color.red)
                    .offset(self.dragAmount)
                    .animation(Animation.default.delay(Double(num)/20), value: enabled)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.dragAmount = CGSize(width: 0, height: 80)
            self.enabled.toggle()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                self.dragAmount = .zero
                self.enabled.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AnimatableModifier` to achieve this effect. here is a sample code:

```swift
extension Double {
    var rad: Double { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var deg: Double { return self * 180 / .pi }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var flag = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Color.clear.overlay(WaveText("Your Text That Need Animate", waveWidth: 6, pct: flag ? 1.0 : 0.0).foregroundColor(.blue)).frame(height: 40)
            Spacer()
        }.onAppear {
            withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2.0).repeatForever()) {
                self.flag.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WaveText: View {
    let text: String
    let pct: Double
    let waveWidth: Int
    var size: CGFloat

    init(_ text: String, waveWidth: Int, pct: Double, size: CGFloat = 34) {
        self.text = text
        self.waveWidth = waveWidth
        self.pct = pct
        self.size = size
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(text).foregroundColor(Color.clear).modifier(WaveTextModifier(text: text, waveWidth: waveWidth, pct: pct, size: size))
    }

    struct WaveTextModifier: AnimatableModifier {
        let text: String
        let waveWidth: Int
        var pct: Double
        var size: CGFloat

        var animatableData: Double {
            get { pct }
            set { pct = newValue }
        }

        func body(content: Content) -> some View {

            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(Array(text.enumerated()), id: \.0) { (n, ch) in
                    Text(String(ch))
                        .scaleEffect(self.effect(self.pct, n, self.text.count, Double(self.waveWidth)))
                }
            }
        }

        func effect(_ pct: Double, _ n: Int, _ total: Int, _ waveWidth: Double) -> CGFloat {
            let n = Double(n)
            let total = Double(total)

            return CGFloat(1 + valueInCurve(pct: pct, total: total, x: n/total, waveWidth: waveWidth))
        }

        func valueInCurve(pct: Double, total: Double, x: Double, waveWidth: Double) -> Double {
            let chunk = waveWidth / total
            let m = 1 / chunk
            let offset = (chunk - (1 / total)) * pct
            let lowerLimit = (pct - chunk) + offset
            let upperLimit = (pct) + offset

            guard x >= lowerLimit && x < upperLimit else { return 0 }

            let angle = ((x - pct - offset) * m)*360-90

            return (sin(angle.rad) + 1) / 2
        }
    }
}
```

You can find refrence and compelete answer [here](https://gist.github.com/swiftui-lab/e5901123101ffad6d39020cc7a810798)